# Excel VBA requiring file extension for workbook reference in some systems

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple excel VBA that is referring multiple files and copying information across to a master before processing. While building this on my own system a workbook reference (working perfectly fine) was written as:

```
Workbooks("key").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:X57").Copy
```

Here key is a .xlsx file

While using this in another system this does not work and it explicitly requires the file extension in every call.

```
Workbooks("key.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:X57").Copy
```

**It would not be extremely difficult for me to make this change although I wanted to understand why this is happening and can I define an Option (guessing!) that would not require me to do so?**

**Why is there difference in behaviour across systems while running the same script?**

Any help would be much appreciated. For me this seems like VBA having a mind of its own.

Comment: If the `key.xlsx` file is saved on both systems, including the file extension when referring to the Workbook objects is the safer option because of Windows _hide extensions setting_ ("If the _hide extensions setting_ is not in effect (meaning that extensions are indeed displayed in Windows), you must include the file extension when you reference a workbook in the Workbooks collection"). See this link for more details [File Extensions And Their Implications In VBA Coding](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/FileExtensions.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the **`key.xlsx`** file is saved on both systems, including the file extension when referring to the **Workbook** objects is the safer option because of Windows *hide extensions* setting:

---

> **The Workbooks Collection Object**
>
> If the *hide extensions* setting is not in effect (meaning that
>   extensions are indeed displayed in Windows), you must include the **xls**
>   extension when you reference a workbook in the **Workbooks** collection.
>   For example, if you have open a workbook named **Book1.xls**, you must use
>
> **`Workbooks("Book1.xls").Activate`**
>
> rather than
>
> **`Workbooks("Book1").Activate`**
>
> to refer to the **Book1** workbook. The second line of code above, without
>   the **xls** extension, will fail with an error 9, *Subscript Out Of Range*,
>   because there is no workbook with the name **Book1**. If the *hide
>   extensions* setting is effect, you can omit the **xls** extension and use
>   either of the following lines of code.
>
> **`Workbooks("Book1").Activate`**
>
> **`Workbooks("Book1.xls").Activate`**
>
> These lines of code assume that you do not have open both an unsaved
>   workbook with the name **Book1** and a saved workbook with the name
>   **Book1.xls**. With the hide extensions setting enabled (so that
>   extensions are hidden in Windows), the two lines of code above are
>   functionally equivalent. As a matter of good programming practice, you
>   should always include the **xls** extension in a workbook name. This
>   ensures that you reference the correct workbook regardless of the
>   value of the hide extensions property.

---

[image: HideExtensions]

---

More details from **[cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com)** for [File Extensions And Their Implications In VBA Coding](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/FileExtensions.aspx)